# How to get habitat map layer information and merge with a point layer

Tags: qgis

I have a habitat map layer with phase 1 habitat polygons, and I have random points acting as sampling points on a different layer. I wondered if there was a way to extract the habitat information that the points are in automatically, and put that into the sample points attribute table? I am very new to using QGIS. I  also have over 5000 sample points, so manually is a last resort.

Comment: Spatial Join: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_joins.html

Comment: You may use the point sampling tool https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/pointsamplingtool/